# Dependecy Injection with MVC other than controllers

Tags: dependency-injection, asp.net-mvc-5

I am trying to understand dependency injection in MVC. I got some idea and implemented successfully with Controllers using extending DefaultControllerFactory and using ninject. But i read something like DI in views , Actions etc.

I didn't get DI in Views or my understanding is wrong. If yes, please tell me use and how to do that. I didn't understand other DI areas in MVC. Please explain the areas where DI is used in MVC other than Controllers

Answer (score 1):

In MVC, you should try and make your Views as independent as possible. Ideally, the only dependency it rely on is the `ViewModel` (other view services and helpers are available through the `WebPageBase` class that all views inherit by default).

Comment: ok thanks, but any specific reason for this. So remove coupling to controller? i din't get about Viewmodel.. please explain

Comment: The main reason is **separation of concerns** that leads to better results in terms of testability, maintainability and scalability. In a very simplified way, you can think of a `Controller` as the place where you deal with `Http / Request / Cookie` etc. `Model` as your data (usually in a shape of C#/VB classes and fetched from some data-source like database) and `View` as your `HTML` output. See more on http://www.microsoftvirtualacademy.com/training-courses/introduction-to-asp-net-mvc

Comment: Thanks and i am also studying from that video.. I am ok with DI and its concept. but my confusion is why in DI view ? and another is where ever i add DI in MVC?

Comment: Are you asking why using Dependency Injection at all? Why is it so integrated into ASP.Net MVC?

Comment: no. I am asking Why dependency injection to Views? Any example scenario or like that

Comment: As I wrote in my answer, there is no built-in mechanism for DI in the Views because Views should not rely on anything other than the view-model.

Comment: Haim is right. In other words, there is no dependency injection for views because views should not have any dependencies to inject.